# PHP in JavaScript and escaping

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using Laravel and i'm making an AJAX request. In the success event I wrote:

```
var name = response.filename;
var path = "<?php echo route('getImage', "name")?>";                        
document.getElementsByClassName("getImage")[0].setAttribute("src", path);
```

But it looks like on the second row the name variable is interpretated as text, not as variable. And the src's value is

> http://localhost/bluedrive/drive/public/getimage/name;

How could I get this right?

Comment: You cannot call any PHP code from your JS. You must run the `route` function on the server side, return its result in the success response and set it as the image `src`.

Comment: Aren't you using blade?

Comment: Not strictly true @AnatoliyArkhipov if OP is putting their javascript in their blade templates.

Comment: Oh, yes, looks like I'm incorrectly understand the question. I thought that the given code is a part of some `success` callback in JS

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, assuming the javascript is in your blade templates.

```
var name = response.filename;
var path = "{{ route('getImage', ['image_name']) }}";
document.getElementsByClassName("getImage")[0].setAttribute("src", path.replace('image_name', name));
```

I think your best option however is to return the full image src back in your ajax response. So your controller may look something like this

```
Input::file('image')->move('/my/filepath', $filename);

return response()->json([
    'image_url' => url('/my/filepath/' . $filename),
]);
```

This returns the url for the image which you can then use in your javascript as below

```
.success(function(response) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("getImage")[0].setAttribute("src", response.image_url);
});
```